# A postgresql db does not exist after its successful creation

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

The following code fails, and I have run out of ideas. How come I get an exception stating that the DB does not exist, when it gets successfully created?

```py
        db_url = f"postgresql://{priv_user}:{priv_password}@{db_host}:{db_port}/grocerylists"
        engine = create_engine(db_url, echo=True, isolation_level='AUTOCOMMIT')
        with engine.connect() as con:
            con.execute(text(f"CREATE DATABASE {db_name};"))
            con.execute(text(f"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE {db_name} TO {db_user};"))
        engine.dispose()

        db_url = f"postgresql://{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_host}:{db_port}/{db_name}"
        engine = create_engine(db_url, echo=True)
        try:
            with engine.connect() as con:
                t = con.execute(text("SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables;"))
        except Exception as _exc:
            print(_exc)
```

Comment: you can try replace `db_url = f"postgresql://{priv_user}:{priv_password}@{db_host}:{db_port}/grocerylists"` with `db_url = f"postgresql://{priv_user}:{priv_password}@{db_host}:{db_port}/postgres"`

Comment: @Furkan that works, the problem shows up with the DBs created through my script.

Comment: So either the database wasn't created or it was and you can't see it afterwards. Which is it?

Comment: @RichardHuxton if I connect to the psql, I can see that db created. However, sqlalchemy is stating it does not exist.

Comment: Without the exact error message it is hard to debug the problem. I would suspect a quoting issue as you do not quote the database name when creating it, so `CREATE DATABASE FooBar` creates the database `foobar` not `FooBar`.

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue: when generating the db name I was using a random string with ASCII letters, which included upper case letters, but in the creation statement I was not using quotes. Therefore, the name was being lower-cased. by using only lower case letters, everything works as expected.